# How do you keep current paginate_button active (bootstrap) after refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, local-storage

I want to click button and keep active currrent button after refresh/reload

My URLs not change when I click other paginate_button , But page is change.

--This button--

https://i.stack.imgur.com/86dJj.jpg

--This code--

```
<ul class="pagination">
<li class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0" id="dataTables-example_previous">
    <a href="#">Previous</a>
</li>
<li class="paginate_button active" aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0">
    <a href="#">1</a>
</li>
<li class="paginate_button " aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0">
    <a href="#">2</a>
</li>
<li class="paginate_button " aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0">
    <a href="#">3</a>       
</li>
<li class="paginate_button " aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0">
    <a href="#">4</a>
</li>
<li class="paginate_button " aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0">
    <a href="#">5</a>
</li>
<li class="paginate_button " aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0">
    <a href="#">6</a>
</li>
<li class="paginate_button " aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0">
    <a href="#">7</a>
</li>
<li class="paginate_button next" aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0" id="dataTables-example_next">
    <a href="#">Next</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

move the `active` class to the `<li>` you want to be active for that page. Example: https://yoursite/page/2 would mean that the second `<li>` would have the active class.

Comment: Hi lazyboy78 ,Thanks for your answer, My URLs not change when I click other paginate_button , But page is change.

Comment: If you mean you're doing this by ajax, then simply do it in the javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can use `window.location.pathname` or `window.location.hash`, depending on how you are working your URLs, to test for the current page. Use that info to select the proper li and set it to active.

Comment: Hi Shawn Rieger ,Thanks for your answer, My URLs not change when I click other paginate_button , But page is change